# Imported products from magento 1.7 site are not visible on magento 1.8 site

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, importexport

I imported all products from magento 1.7 site to  freshly installed 1.8 site. both are different sites. but products are same. after "run Profile" , i got message on screen "import successfull". Products are present in admin panel. but it's not visible on frontend.

Please give me your suggestions to make products visible on frontend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Admin Panel,

i) Goto Manage Products

ii) Then Select the products which are not displaying in the frontend

iii) Then Select the Update Attributes in the Action

iv) Then Add those products to correct websites.

Re-index the catalog products.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, you are genius , i got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Als look into the settings of the stock

You can eassily disable the stock option in the backoffice

Go to System => Configuration => Catalog => Stock

In the Options section if the first option is Yes put it to No and save it

Comment: Hi, thanks i will look at it. I am new to magento. is it require to disable the stock option? Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that the products that you have imported has a standard value for the stock... It's not required but if you have issues like you had than it's a good way to determine if thats the problem ;)

It needs to configured right, in the beginning that i started Magento i had a simular problem, i changed the stock to off and i saw all the products ;)

Comment: Your welcome mate